# iOS layout: alternative to tabs?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar, uitabbar

I'm working on a iPhone app which shows an mobile webform in a UIWebView. I'm using a default iOS layout with a navigation and tab bar.

[image: Screenshot of iPhone App]

The mobile webform is displayed in a UIWebView in the white area. Since the webform has a lot of input fields, we really need as must space for it as possible. Because of this, we are planing to remove the tabs in the bottom. Over time, there will be more tabs/sections, so it is not a solution to just add a button for each section in the left side of the navigation bar. On a iPad a popover could easily be used to handle this.

Is there a standard iOS layout mechanism to handle this change of sections/views without using tabs?

Comment: You might want to consider asking this question on http://ux.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something long the lines of Path or the new Facebook app and have the "table of contents" behind the Navbar and the navbar slides away (along with the child view) to reveal it. When done right (ie smoothly) I think the effect is really cool.

This would also work great as you add more and more options, since the table could just scroll.

Here is a framework that might be you started: http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/iiviewdeckcontroller

Answer (score 0):

I would consider replacing the navigation bar's title with a control that lets you switch between tabs. You can assign the bar's titleView property to a control or a button and it will generally do the right thing.

If you're limited to 2-3 tabs, you could simply use a UISegmentedControl.

If you want more, you could use a button which, when tapped, pops up a view that allows you to select the view you want. This could be a modal table view, or you could slide up a UIPickerView from the bottom of the screen, similar to the keyboard.

I use this technique in an app of my own, [screenshots here](http://www.fatwatchapp.com/tour/#log). Tapping the button cycles between views (in this case, I'm changing the contents of the table cells); tap-and-hold slides up a picker.

Comment: As I wrote, we will add more sections/tabs over time.

Comment: Oh, I see. Your use of the word "sections" was confusing me, since that's usually used to describe sections of a table view.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility would be to arrange your different forms on pages in a scroll view with a page control at the bottom, à la Weather. The best option, though, if you’re going to have a particularly long list and want to keep your screen real estate, is probably the FB/Path-style sidebar table.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a [`UIActionSheet`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html) but I think it in other situations would be more stylish to use a controller like the [`IIViewDeckController`](https://github.com/Inferis/ViewDeck).